# Is InstantAllowed true required to fastTrack referendum?

Tags: kusama, substrate-parachain-template, democracy

I am trying to fast track a referendum but the runtime has `InstantAllowed` set to `false`. When i try to execute the extrinsic I get a `democracy.InstantNotAllowed` error.

Also, the `votingPeriod` and `Delay` parameters are slightly ambiguous. Does it require the block number or number of blocks?

[image]

```
parameter_types! {
    pub LaunchPeriod: BlockNumber = prod_or_fast!(2 * DAYS, 1, "KAB_LAUNCH_PERIOD");
    pub VotingPeriod: BlockNumber = prod_or_fast!(7 * DAYS, 1 * MINUTES, "KAB_VOTING_PERIOD");
    pub FastTrackVotingPeriod: BlockNumber = prod_or_fast!(3 * DAYS , 1 * MINUTES, "KAB_FAST_TRACK_VOTING_PERIOD");
    pub const MinimumDeposit: Balance = 1 * CENTS;
    pub EnactmentPeriod: BlockNumber = prod_or_fast!(1 * DAYS, 1, "KAB_ENACTMENT_PERIOD");
    pub CooloffPeriod: BlockNumber = prod_or_fast!(7 * DAYS, 1 * MINUTES, "KAB_COOLOFF_PERIOD");
    pub const InstantAllowed: bool = false;
    pub const MaxVotes: u32 = 100;
    pub const MaxProposals: u32 = 100;
    pub const PreimageByteDeposit: Balance = 1 * BILLICENTS;
}

impl pallet_democracy::Config for Runtime {
    type Proposal = Call;
    type Event = Event;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type EnactmentPeriod = EnactmentPeriod;
    type VoteLockingPeriod = EnactmentPeriod;
    type LaunchPeriod = LaunchPeriod;
    type VotingPeriod = VotingPeriod;
    type MinimumDeposit = MinimumDeposit;
    type ExternalOrigin = EnsureSigned<AccountId>;
    type ExternalMajorityOrigin = EnsureSigned<AccountId>;
    type ExternalDefaultOrigin = EnsureSigned<AccountId>;
    type FastTrackOrigin = EnsureSigned<AccountId>;
    type InstantOrigin = EnsureSigned<AccountId>;
    type InstantAllowed = InstantAllowed;
    type FastTrackVotingPeriod = FastTrackVotingPeriod;
    type CancellationOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type BlacklistOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type CancelProposalOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type VetoOrigin = EnsureSigned<AccountId>;
    type CooloffPeriod = CooloffPeriod;
    type PreimageByteDeposit = PreimageByteDeposit;
    type OperationalPreimageOrigin = EnsureSigned<AccountId>;
    type Slash = Treasury;
    type Scheduler = Scheduler;
    type PalletsOrigin = OriginCaller;
    type MaxVotes = MaxVotes;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_democracy::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
    type MaxProposals = MaxProposals;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`votingPeriod` is the period for which voting will be open (in number of blocks). For the extrinsic to succeed one of the two conditions must be met:

- `votingPeriod` is greater or equal to the `FastTrackVotingPeriod` defined in the pallet's config and origin for the call is `FastTrackOrigin`, or
- origin for the call is `InstantOrigin` and `InstantAllowed` is `true`.

From the error raised (`InstantNotAllowed`) I infer that you must have specified a `votingPeriod` lower than `FastTrackVotingPeriod` so the code assumed that it is supposed to be an *instant* referendum, but this failed because `InstantAllowed` is `false` in your config.

---

`delay` is also number of blocks. It's the number of blocks between accepting the proposal in a referendum and enacting it.

Comment: Ok thats clear. i have prod or fast macro, but perhaps my parachain is set to live on the staging net so its expecting blocknumber to be at least 3 days. Ok makes sense

Comment: @Decentration Please consider marking the question as resolved.